# T-SQL 2008: Parse String

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, substring, reverse

I have the following location as a string:

```
\\Windows\UnitB\CU1234_001\
```

I want to return the `CU1234_001` part only. The query which I need to use needs to be dynamic since this string will change and it could be longer or shorter (it will all the time end in "\".

I've tried to used something like this but this just eliminate the last "\" and returns the rest of the string:

```
select 
    substring('\\Windows\UnitB\CU1234_001\',
              1, (len('\\Windows\UnitB\CU1234_001\') - (Charindex('\',  
  reverse(rtrim('\\Windows\UnitB\CU1234_001\'))))))
```

Comment: You started a substring at index 1 on "\\Windows\UnitB\CU1234_001\'. That's not going to return CU1234_001

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of string functions to extract what you want:

```
SELECT REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(col),
                         2,
                         CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(col), 2) - 2))
FROM yourTable
```